# Most efficient way to query a database multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a small tool for myself to query through a large database (1.7GB, only one table)

First, it queries:

```
SELECT ip FROM player_analytics WHERE auth= :auth GROUP BY ip
```

Afterwards, for each row that is returned it queries:

```
SELECT auth FROM player_analytics WHERE ip= :ip AND auth<> :auth GROUP by auth
```

But, this whole proccess takes ~2 minutes and sometimes even more, and I wondered if there is any way to make it faster and take less resources.

I'll appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: First thing to check is your indexes. I'm guessing you don't have one for `ip, auth`.

Comment: So you want all authors that have the same IP as the author you provide as input

Comment: @juergend: I'm willing to bet that `auth` is not a short for `author` here. :)

Comment: No I don't, what I've sent is 1:1 how it is in my code. Can you give me some information about indexes and how they help?

Comment: auth is a unique ID, basically, I want to find all IPs behind one auth and then query all the ips  to find more auths with that IP

Comment: First place to start is the [documentation on indexes in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html). You generally need an index for anything you query regularly, so everything in your `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try phrasing this as a single query:

```
select distinct pa2.auth
from player_analytics pa join
     player_analytics pa2
     on pa.ip = pa2.ip and
        pa.auth = :auth and
        pa2.auth <> :auth;
```

For this query, you want two indexes on `player_analytics(auth, ip)` and `player_analytics(ip, auth).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT pa2.auth
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT pa.ip, pa.auth
    FROM player_analytics pa
    WHERE pa.auth= :auth
) pa1
JOIN player_analytics pa2 
    ON  p2.ip    = p1.ip
    AND p2.auth <> p1.auth
```

You should have an index on `auth` for `WHERE` and an index on `ip` for the join.